Tree shaking and named vs. default imports – what is the truth in 2024?
I have been contemplating about an ADR for our project regarding a best practice on default vs. named imports, including how our components should be structured regarding their exports.
Reading up on different recommendations regarding the impact on tree shaking, i find conflicting information out there.
There is team "default imports":

https://dev.to/hitanshimehta/best-coding-practices-in-reactjs-4gmp
https://spiegelmock.com/2023/04/02/mastering-javascript-tree-shaking/

Then there is team "named imports":

https://medium.com/@sargun.kohli152/reducing-bundle-size-for-react-and-mui-using-tree-shaking-a-comprehensive-guide-f4bd709bc0c3#e90e
https://dev.to/bragaru-i/react-performance-boost-it-with-tree-shaking-3alp#2-import-only-what-you-need
also i remember having read that the React project itself prefers named exports instead of default exports for everything (cannot find the source for that though atm)

I assume it may be a relevant distinction when talking about imports from a module vs. a component. Also i wonder if there's fundamental differences between Webpack and Vite (which currently uses Rollup for production builds).
Could somebody give a comprehensive answer what are the best practices regarding named vs. default imports and exports for most efficient tree shaking in 2024?

This is off-topic, as there is no programming question here - just a solicitation for opinions and recommendations.
